# Draw a line in UIView based on animated CGPoint.x

Tags: uiview, core-animation

I have am trying to draw a vertical line in a UIView (call it View A) based on the center of subview of "View A".

The subview animates well, however, the line drawing is not animated. it bumps to the final position.

For instance if subview is at CGPoint(0,100) and I want to animate to CGPoint(100,100). 
THe subview moves as expected, however, the line drawing does not it only appears at CGPoint(100,100) throughout the animation.

Of course inside the animation block I am calling [self setNeedsDisplay]

The code I am using is as follows(the pointView is the subview mentioned above) :

```
CGPointView newCetner = CGPointMake(100,100);
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{                
 pointView.center = newCenter;
 [self setNeedsDisplay];
}];
```

in the drawRect method I have the following code:

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(pointView.frame), pointView.center.y-100 );    
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(pointView.frame), pointView.center.y+100 );    
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Any ideas how I might force the view to redraw in accordance with the animation block?

Answer (score 0):

By default, animation works by storing the start and final versions of the view, and applying some inexpensive transform to move from one to the other. Intermediate versions of the view are not drawn with `drawRect:`.

You can request that `drawRect:` be called for the intermediate steps by passing the option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` to `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. Be sure that `drawRect:` is fast when using this option, since it will be called often.

Comment: your explanation is clear, however when I tried passing the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent to animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: I continue to get the same affect. It doesn't draw intermedate steps.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in and make sure that `drawRect:` is being called as expected. Check your `frame` and `center` values to see that they are being iterated as expected. BTW, you shouldn't need the call to `setNeedsDisplay`.